# Coder for a POJO in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to create a dummy PCollection with my custom objects as follows:

```
PCollection<MyClass> pipelineProcessingResults =  pipeline.apply(Create.of(new MyClass(.., ..)));
```

MyClass class is as follows:

```
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
public class MyClass {
  AnotherComplexClass _obj;
  Urn _urn
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.reflect.TypeVisitor.visit(TypeVisitor.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.reflect.Types.getComponentType(Types.java:197)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.getComponentType(TypeToken.java:563)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.isArray(TypeToken.java:512)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TypeDescriptor.isArray(TypeDescriptor.java:193)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.utils.ReflectUtils.getIterableComponentType(ReflectUtils.java:196)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.FieldValueTypeInformation.getIterableComponentType(FieldValueTypeInformation.java:274)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.FieldValueTypeInformation.forGetter(FieldValueTypeInformation.java:189)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.JavaBeanSchema$GetterTypeSupplier.get(JavaBeanSchema.java:74)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.utils.StaticSchemaInference.schemaFromClass(StaticSchemaInference.java:92)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.utils.StaticSchemaInference.fieldFromType(StaticSchemaInference.java:166)
```

The class AnotherComplexClass may contain multiple fields which in turn are composed of other classes.

Which coder will best suit my purpose? Should I create a custom coder? Using the @DefaultSchema annotation did not help me much. I tried using SerializableCoder, but it throws a compiler error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'of(java.lang.Class<MyClass>)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - Custom Coder

Since you have complex nested data types, you can define a custom coder and use it with the @DefaultCoder annotator. Details see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#annotating-custom-type-default-coder.

```java
public class MyCoder implements Coder {
  public static Coder<T> of (Class<T> clazz) {...}
}

@DefaultCoder(MyCoder.class)
public class MyClass {...}
```

Option 2 - Serializable

You can also make sure that all your POJO classes implement Serializable and by default, Java SDK uses the SerializableCoder. But it's inefficient and non-deterministic.

Option 3 - Avro

You can use AvroCoder and use Avro to generate your classes. https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html

Option 4 - Protocol Buffer

Similar to Avro, you can use Protocol Buffer to define your schema and classes. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial.